# method to prevent "divided by zero-error"

Tags: python, for-loop, divide-by-zero, openrouteservice

im running this:

```
for dataset in waycategory_values:
        if dataset['value'] in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]: 
            total_highway_distance += dataset['distance']

    for dataset in waycategory_values:
        total_distance += dataset['distance']

    highway_perc = (total_highway_distance / total_distance)

    print(highway_perc)
```

It is possible that total_distance is zero. Is there a smooth way to keep the script going and just print 0 when the total distance is 0. I was thinking about adding +1 to total_distance everytime - but isn't there a better way?

in my mind the below is circulating, but it's not working:

```
if total_distance == 0:
    total_distance = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "not working" because what the code you wrote doesn't use the logic you say you want.  What you described in words looks like this:

```
# print 0 when the total distance is 0

if total_distance == 0:
    highway_perc = 0
else:
    highway_perc = total_highway_distance / total_distance

print(highway_perc)
```

---

You can also do this in one line:

```
highway_perc = 0 if total_distance == 0 else total_highway_distance / total_distance
```

Comment: thanks, it's late and I had to get it right - I declare you as my savior